# Find rows for an id where value changes in any of the coloumn in sql

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table with say 10 columns where the unique identifier is id column.
I need print all the rows where value for any given id changes for any of the 10 coloums.
Eg:

```
Id  name    city    state   address mail    phn number  store no    business name   date
1   adam    california  ca  acbb street xyz@gmail.com   12345   456 abc pvt 01-01-2017
1   adam    newyork Ny  avc xyz@gmail.com   12345   456 abc pvt 11-03-2018
1   adam    newyork Ny  avc xyz@gmail.com   12345   456 abcd pvt    24-03-2018
2   brian   dallas  Tx  sasa    sasa@gmail.com      21212   dsdssd ltd  01-01-2017
2   brian   dallas  Tx  sasa    sasa@gmail.com  232323  21212   dsdssd ltd  01-01-2017
3   donald  dallas  Tx  qwer    qwwqw@gmail.com 2121212 435345  sffsss ltd  23-01-2017
```

As shown above for id 1 there is a change from the first row to 2nd row on city state address so that should come .also for id 1 the 3rd row changes only business name so that should also be printed.
So basically for an id the status for that id before that date should be checked and if there is any change in any column it should be printed.
Same goes for id 2.For id 3 there is only one entry so that should not be printed.

The check needs to be done based on date for an id.

The data set that I have is in millions so would need a fine tuned query.

Comment: So the output should be all the 3 rows pertaining to id 1 since it is changing across all dates.Both the rows for id 2 but id 3 should not appear as it is having only one occurence.

Comment: Are you really using both Postgres and Redshift?

Comment: no only redshift

Comment: @niteshjha . . . All your sample data has changes from the previous rows.  I can't follow what you are really trying to do.  Desired results -- in a tabular format -- would really help.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column for row number( for example ROWID), you can simply select all rows that has a pair (based on ID) in previous records and check if any of the last row columns differs from the first one:

```
select a.* from [yourTable] a
inner join [yourTable] b
on a.Id = b.Id where a.RowId > b.RowId 
and (a.name <> b.name OR a.city <> b.city OR a.state <> b.state OR a.address <> b.address ... )
```

Comment: No i dont have a row id coloumn..can we dynamically add row number to this

Comment: We need a column to determine witch row we should select as master and witch one is update, so if we don't have ID column, we can use others like "date" so our where clause will be changed to : where a.date > b.date